# Translating back an unknown binary file!? is it possible?

Tags: c#, winforms, binary, decode, binaryreader

I have a program which saves it result files in a binary file. It is also posible within the program to export the result files into XML format.

Since the progam itself is awfull at browsing its results, I wrote a program myself to read this result files, but obviously using the XML format.

The problem is, the XML files exported from binary files are huge! while a binary file which can be used by the orginal program is about 100 KB, The same file exported to XML is around 2~3 MB.

I want to know is there a way that I can find out how to read the orginal binary files!

Comment: What is the problem with 2-3MB XML? You can read it once into memory and then use LINQ to query it. You can read binary file - no problem, but it is unlikely you could restore original objects unless you know how they were saved.

Comment: Are you asking how to deserialize a binary file that was written to binary by the same app?

Comment: @oleksii one xml file is not a problem but I sometimes load up to 50 of them in one go, so it reduces the performance

Comment: @George My question is how do deserialize a binary file while you don't know how it was serilized!

Comment: @Sean87 How would the application deserializing the binary file know the metadata/type of the object being deserialized?  How would you cast it into a usable object?

Comment: I dont know! Thats what I am asking for!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data out of a binary file you'll need to know the structure of it. If you don't know the structure, I think this will be a hopeless endeavour. The xml file is so much bigger, because it contains the structure in addition to the data. You can read and interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the program source code, if it is not available - open this program in ILDASM or Reflector, and try to understand how binary file are created. Probably this is done using binary serialization.

You can define your own types which are exact copy of original types, including serialization attributes, and load them using binary serialization.

However, every change in third party file format may require you to change your program. I think it is better to use XML.

Comment: ildasm cant open any of the exe or dll files in the program :(

Comment: The orginal progam is dating back to 2005...I am not sure if it is programmed in C at all, ILDASM says it does not have common CLR header...neverthelss I will try with some other disassemblers to see what can happen!

Comment: So, it is not .NET Assembly! It was not clear from the question. In this case my advice is useless. I don't think you really want to read native Assembly code for this program and understand binary file structure by so difficult way :(